# Travelling to Dubai

Tags: visas, dubai, ghana

I applied for a 90-day visa for Dubai and it has been issued on 24/02/2019 and its *Visa validity date* is given as 24/04/2019 instead of 24/05/2019. Can I stay 90 days before returning or do I have to do something about it before going?

Comment: Could you improve the title by editing the question?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn’t have to worry but be prepared to come back after 60 days.

> Depending on your plan, tourist visas to the UAE can be issued for 30 days or 90 days duration, single entry or multiple entry.

- https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visiting-and-exploring-the-uae/tourist-visa

It can be extended while there:

> The new system now allows people on visit or tourist visas to extend their stay in the UAE for 30 days, for two times, after expiration of the entry permits," said Brigadier Saeed Rakan Al Rashidi, acting director-general of Foreigners Affairs and Ports at the Federal Authority for Identity and Citizenship.

- https://m.khaleejtimes.com/news/general/visit-tourist-visa-holders/-can-extend-their-stay-for-up-to-60-days-in-uae-

Note you can only extend a tourist visa.

> However, the new rule for extension does not apply on the following categories:
>
> - visitors and tourists who are residents in GCC countries
> - residents accompanying GCC nationals
> - those on special entry permits
> - those on 96-hour permit for special missions.